# Laravel- Redirecting users with a dynamic parameter through controller

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, dynamicparameters

I have set up the web routing for my url to show as per
localhost/testapp/public/{user}/hello

with this current setting

```
Route::prefix('{user}')->middleware('user')->group(function () {
 Route::prefix('welcome')->group(function () {
  Route::view('/', 'layout.index')->name('index');
  Route::view('thank-you', 'layout.thank-you')->name('thankyou');
 });
 Route::get('/', 'HomeController@redirect');
});
```

`Route::view('/', 'layout.index')->name('index');` this line works fine the way i wanted it to work, however I wasn't able to get the `HomeController@redirect` to work the way I want it to.

The idea is for the user to be redirected when `localhost/testapp/public/{user}` is being entered, it would redirect user to the page `localhost/testapp/public/{user}/hello`

This is how the HomeController looks

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
 public function redirect(Request $request)
 {
  return redirect(['user' => $request, config('settings.default_user')].'/welcome');
 }
}
```

whereby if the dynamic parameter is somehow not received, I would stick to the default user "admin" that is being stored in my settings.php within the config folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [optional parameter](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#parameters-optional-parameters) in the routes file, otherwise it will show a 404 if no `{user}` is provided

```
Route::prefix('/{user?}')
```

Then with this in `config/settings.php`

```
<?php
return ['default_user' => 456];
```

And this in the `HomeController`

```
public function redirect(Request $request)
{
    if (empty($request->user)) {
        return redirect(config('settings.default_user') . '/welcome');
    } else {
        return redirect($request->user . '/welcome');
    }
}
```

Now when I try in my browser

- `/123` redirects me to `/123/welcome`.
- `/` redirects me to `456/welcome`.